# Is it possible to run a command on a running Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's say I have an app, started with `mvn spring-boot:run`, or `java -jar myApp.jar`.

After a while I want to trigger the execution of a method, from command line. Is it possible ?

I've checked `CommandLineRunner` but is seems it can only execute code right after the app boot, while I want to execute a method whenever I want.

Comment: check that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356405/how-to-run-a-command-at-terminal-from-java-program

Comment: that post tells how to run a command from Java, it's the opposite of what I'm looking for

Comment: You can try mbeans and cli invocation https://www.baeldung.com/jmx-mbean-shell-access or write custom "terminal controller", like servlet in webapps. Wait commands in loop and handle them.

Answer (score 0):

There was Spring [RMI](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_method_invocation) (cf this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-rmi)) but it has been [deprecated by Spring 5.3](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework/spring-context/5.3.7/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiProxyFactoryBean.html), for [security reasons](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24434).

An answer should lie in [Spring integration doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html) (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735258/whats-the-alternative-for-spring-rmi-since-its-deprecated)).